# How to make a title page with beamer without navigation bar, using theme warsaw

Tags: beamer, titles

Using `beamer`, how to make a title page without a navigation bar, using the theme "warsaw"  or how to get a title page from another theme, but maintaining the navigation bar on the other frames?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The »plain« option for the `frame` environment is probably what you are looking for.

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Details about that in the [beamer](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) manual.